# No outputLatency in AudioContext

Tags: html, html5-audio, web-audio-api, audiocontext, webkitaudiocontext

I'm trying to access the outputLatency feature in Chrome 64, but the property is undefined.

According to the documentation it should work only on Chrome https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/AudioContext/outputLatency

I know the feature is in experimental state but is there a way to access it ? Like changing a flag in Chrome to activate this feature ?

```js
const audioCtx = new AudioContext();
console.log(audioCtx.outputLatency);
$("#result").html("AudioContext.outputLatency = " + audioCtx.outputLatency)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seem to be a fault on the part of the MDN documentation for the desktop devices at least. The `outputLatency` has not yet been implemented it seems and was [reported](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=785409&q=outputLatency&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Stars%20ReleaseBlock%20Component%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified) back in November (2015 that is..).

As of now there doesn't appear to be any experimental implementation behind flags neither.

(I have reported the issue with MDN [here](https://github.com/mdn/browser-compat-data/issues/1215)).